# Efficiently getting all divisors of a given number

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, factorization

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995069/finding-factors-of-a-number-not-getting-accurate-results), we can get all divisors of a number through the following codes.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i){
    if (num % i == 0)
        cout << i << endl;
}
```

For example, the divisors of number `24` are `1 2 3 4 6 8 12 24`.

After searching some related posts, I did not find any good solutions. Is there any efficient way to accomplish this?

My solution:

1. Find all prime factors of the given number through this [solution](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/).
2. Get all possible combinations of those prime factors.

However, it doesn't seem to be a good one.

Comment: What do you think is "not good" about your proposed prime number approach? Off the top of my head it sounds like the most feasible approach for large numbers. Factorising is known to be a "hard" (i.e. slow) problem. Much of the world depends on this fact. Do you know the maximum size of input you would expect? A less general approach might be to precalculate a table of primes suitable for the input range, and use that.

Comment: I think `get all possible combinations of those prime factors` can not be efficient.

Comment: It may be better on average to get only the prime factors and then generate the combinations. That doesn't help if the original number is prime, but if it isn't then you'll do far fewer divisions.

Comment: Why not? Put it this way: with a generative approach, you deal with just the actual factors. With an iterative approach, you have to deal with vastly more numbers that are **not** factors, even if discounting them is quick. Not doing the analysis, but I would assume that is quicker, even if the process of generating combinations is slow. For large numbers, the amount of potential factors you have to deal with is going to grow fast enough to outweigh the more expensive combination computation. Disclaimer: I am guessing, not calculating.

Comment: And if the inputs are very large, it would probably be prudent to run it through a prime check first (e.g. google Rabin-Miller). But this may be overkill for the scope of what you are doing.

Comment: @BoBTFish, you are right. I am also guessing my idea is not efficient.

Comment: @zangw "*I think get all possible combinations of those prime factors can not be efficient.*" Huh? Compared to finding the factors in the first place, that's absolutely trivial -- it's basically just counting.

Comment: @zangw By "efficient", do you mean "code is easy to write"? If yes, see the answer by Yu Hao.

Comment: @anatolyg, sort of, also I want to implement it with less time complexity.

Comment: If you just happen to be looking for perfect numbers, then there's a much more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @zangw "get all possible combinations of those prime factors" is trivial. See my answer below. Writing maths in comments is too hard.

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992904/enumerate-factors-of-a-number-directly-in-ascending-order-without-sorting).

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Factors are paired. `1` and `24`, `2` and `12`, `3` and `8`, `4` and `6`.

An improvement of your algorithm could be to iterate to the square root of `num` instead of all the way to `num`, and then calculate the paired factors using `num / i`.

Comment: Also, since you only care about the whole part of the square root, you can use a simple square-root algorithm.

Comment: If this is a repeated algorithm, i.e. want to find the divisors of lots of numbers, generating all the primes up to root(n) with a sieve and then generating the prime decomposition, and iterating over it to get all the factors, will be much faster. This is because primes are logarithmically distributed, so large primes tend to be far apart. So you have far fewer divisions.

Comment: @phil_20686, what you mentioned is it a dynamic programming based approach?

Comment: you can also save on square root by doing `for (int i = 1; i * i <= num; i++)`

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary That's incorrect. You can avoid the square root using `for (int i = 1; (i + 1) * (i + 1) <= num; i++)`. Your formula misses out on e.g. `num = 90`. It does have a divisor of `10` but `i = 10` will break the loop.

Comment: @l33t No, it's correct, by your logic it also misses 45, 10 is already counted by 9 as divisor, we have to take both `x` and `num / x` in this method, since 9 * 9 <= 90, we take 9 and 90/9 = 10.

Comment: You're right. I forgot about that correlation.

Answer (score 32):

You should really check till square root of num as sqrt(num) * sqrt(num) = num:

Something on these lines:

```
int square_root = (int) sqrt(num) + 1;
for (int i = 1; i < square_root; i++) { 
    if (num % i == 0&&i*i!=num)
        cout << i << num/i << endl;
    if (num % i == 0&&i*i==num)
        cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to do that.  Any C compiler with optimizations turned on will do that (Clang does it for any optimization level higher than 0, for example).  I would be more worried about the unmatched paren on the first line.

Comment: Since `i<square_root`, `i*i<num`, there is no need to prove if `i*i==num`, and after the for, you should prove if `square_root*square_root==num`.

Answer (score 19):

There is no efficient way in the sense of algorithmic complexity (an algorithm with polynomial complexity) known in science by now. So iterating until the square root as already suggested is mostly as good as you can be.

Mainly because of this, a large part of the currently used cryptography is based on the assumption that it is very time consuming to compute a prime factorization of any given integer.

Answer (score 11):

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#define pii pair<int, int>

#define MAX 46656
#define LMT 216
#define LEN 4830
#define RNG 100032

unsigned base[MAX / 64], segment[RNG / 64], primes[LEN];

#define sq(x) ((x)*(x))
#define mset(x,v) memset(x,v,sizeof(x))
#define chkC(x,n) (x[n>>6]&(1<<((n>>1)&31)))
#define setC(x,n) (x[n>>6]|=(1<<((n>>1)&31)))

// http://zobayer.blogspot.com/2009/09/segmented-sieve.html
void sieve()
{
    unsigned i, j, k;
    for (i = 3; i<LMT; i += 2)
        if (!chkC(base, i))
            for (j = i*i, k = i << 1; j<MAX; j += k)
                setC(base, j);
    primes[0] = 2;
    for (i = 3, j = 1; i<MAX; i += 2)
        if (!chkC(base, i))
            primes[j++] = i;
}


//http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/
vector <pii> factors;
void primeFactors(int num)
{
    int expo = 0;   
    for (int i = 0; primes[i] <= sqrt(num); i++)
    {
        expo = 0;
        int prime = primes[i];
        while (num % prime == 0){
            expo++;
            num = num / prime;
        }
        if (expo>0)
            factors.push_back(make_pair(prime, expo));
    }

    if ( num >= 2)
        factors.push_back(make_pair(num, 1));

}

vector <int> divisors;
void setDivisors(int n, int i) {
    int j, x, k;
    for (j = i; j<factors.size(); j++) {
        x = factors[j].first * n;
        for (k = 0; k<factors[j].second; k++) {
            divisors.push_back(x);
            setDivisors(x, j + 1);
            x *= factors[j].first;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    sieve();
    int n, x, i; 
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        primeFactors(x);
        setDivisors(1, 0);
        divisors.push_back(1);
        sort(divisors.begin(), divisors.end());
        cout << divisors.size() << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < divisors.size(); j++) {
            cout << divisors[j] << " "; 
        }
        cout << "\n";
        divisors.clear();
        factors.clear();
    }
}
```

The first part, sieve() is used to find the prime numbers and put them in primes[] array. Follow the link to find more about that code (bitwise sieve).

The second part primeFactors(x) takes an integer (x) as input and finds out its prime factors and corresponding exponent, and puts them in vector factors[]. For example, primeFactors(12) will populate factors[] in this way:

```
factors[0].first=2, factors[0].second=2
factors[1].first=3, factors[1].second=1
```

as 12 = 2^2 * 3^1

The third part setDivisors() recursively calls itself to calculate all the divisors of x, using the vector factors[] and puts them in vector divisors[].

It can calculate divisors of any number which fits in int. Also it is quite fast.

Answer (score 6):

Plenty of good solutions exist for finding all the prime factors of not too large numbers. I just wanted to point out, that once you have them, no computation is required to get all the factors.

if `N = p_1^{a}*p_{2}^{b}*p_{3}^{c}.....`

Then the number of factors is clearly `(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)....` since every factor can occur *zero* up to *a* times.

e.g. `12 = 2^2*3^1` so it has `3*2 = 6` factors. `1,2,3,4,6,12`

======

I originally thought that you just wanted the number of distinct factors. But the same logic applies. You just iterate over the set of numbers corresponding to the possible combinations of exponents.

so int he example above:

```
00
01
10
11
20
21
```

gives you the `6` factors.

Comment: This is suboptimal as you are doing the same multiplications over and over again.

Answer (score 3):

**If you want all divisors to be printed in sorted order**

```
int i;
for(i=1;i*i<n;i++){             /*print all the divisors from 1(inclusive) to
    if(n%i==0){                   √n (exclusive) */   
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }
}
for( ;i>=1;i--){                /*print all the divisors from √n(inclusive) to
  if(n%i==0){                     n (inclusive)*/   
      cout<<(n/i)<<" ";
  }
}
```

**If divisors can be printed in any order**

```
for(int j=1;j*j<=n;j++){
    if(n%j==0){
        cout<<j<<" ";
        if(j!=(n/j))
           cout<<(n/j)<<" ";
    }
}
```

Both approaches have complexity O(√n)

Comment: I like the approach to output in ascending order, and the comment on complexity. Please make it a habit to comment&document code: *What is everything* (externally visible) *good for*?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I will note that. Also, thank you for upvoting my solution.

Comment: It is returning duplicates, like for 6 it returns `1:2:2:3:6`.

Comment: i believe the bound on the second for loop is mistaken, it should be i >=  i*i  not i >=1 this way it will not print the numbers lesser than sqrt(n) twice

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Java Implementation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26753963/10627133) approach:

```
public static int countAllFactors(int num)
{
    TreeSet<Integer> tree_set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i * i <= num; i+=1)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            tree_set.add(i);
            tree_set.add(num / i);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(tree_set);
    return tree_set.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use modified sieve for getting all the factors for all numbers in range [1, N-1].

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < N; j += i) {
        ans[j].push_back(i);
    }
}
```

The time complexity is *O(N * log(N))* as the sum of harmonic series *1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/N* can be approximated to *log(N)*.

More info about time complexity : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3367064

P.S : Usually in programming problems, the task will include several queries where each query represents a different number and hence precalculating the divisors for all numbers in a range at once would be beneficial as the lookup takes O(1) time in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
for( int i = 1; i * i <= num; i++ )
{
/* upto sqrt is because every divisor after sqrt
    is also found when the number is divided by i.
   EXAMPLE like if number is 90 when it is divided by 5
    then you can also see that 90/5 = 18
    where 18 also divides the number.
   But when number is a perfect square
    then num / i == i therefore only i is the factor
*/
```

Comment: This looks a suggestion to improve the code from the question rather than a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this,it can find divisors of verrrrrrrrrry big numbers (pretty efficiently :-))
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

vector<double> D;

void divs(double N);
double mod(double &n1, double &n2);
void push(double N);
void show();

int main()
{
    double N; 
    cout << "\n Enter number: "; cin >> N;

    divs(N); // find and push divisors to D

    cout << "\n Divisors of "<<N<<": "; show(); // show contents of D (all divisors of N)

_getch(); // used visual studio, if it isn't supported replace it by "getch();"
return(0);
}

void divs(double N)
{
    for (double i = 1; i <= sqrt(N); ++i)
    {
        if (!mod(N, i)) { push(i); if(i*i!=N) push(N / i); }
    }
}

double mod(double &n1, double &n2)
{
    return(((n1/n2)-floor(n1/n2))*n2);
}

void push(double N)
{
    double s = 1, e = D.size(), m = floor((s + e) / 2);
    while (s <= e)
    {   
        if (N==D[m-1]) { return; }
        else if (N > D[m-1]) { s = m + 1; }
        else { e = m - 1; }
        m = floor((s + e) / 2);
    }
    D.insert(D.begin() + m, N);
}

void show()
{
    for (double i = 0; i < D.size(); ++i) cout << D[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result_num;
bool flag;

cout << "Number          Divisors\n";

for (int number = 1; number <= 35; number++)
{
    flag = false;
    cout << setw(3) << number << setw(14);

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) 
    {
        result_num = number % i;

        if (result_num == 0 && flag == true)
        {
            cout << "," << i;
        }

        if (result_num == 0 && flag == false)
        {
            cout << i;
        }

        flag = true;
    }

    cout << endl;   
}
cout << "Press enter to continue.....";
cin.ignore();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i*i <= num; ++i)
{
    if (num % i == 0)
    cout << i << endl;
    if (num/i!=i)
    cout << num/i << endl;
}
```

Comment: This looks *effective*: executing this has the effect required. However, the question explicitly asks for an `efficient way to accomplish this`: can you please argue how this is a) less work than the approach presented in the question b) simpler than other solutions investing less work, still? How does this answer compare to 40+ other answers?

Comment: (`this has the effect required` - well, almost: lacks a `if (num / i != i)
    cout << num/i << endl;`.)

Comment: In my sense , using i*i and removing the sqrt function makes it faster.

Comment: By all means: put the arguments *what* makes this a good solution *in your answer* (and not in comments on comments). I misremembered the number of votes for the question as the number of prior answers - my bad, there are only ten of those. Then again, half of them explicitly iterate till *n < i\*i*, only. You could try to get rid of the multiplication too - recall what you know about the series of odd numbers.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22043678)

Answer (score 0):

```
//DIVISORS IN TIME COMPLEXITY sqrt(n)

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define ll long long

int main()
{
    ll int n;
    cin >> n;

    for(ll i = 2;  i <= sqrt(n); i++)
    {
        if (n%i==0)
        {
            if (n/i!=i)
                cout << i << endl << n/i<< endl;
            else
                cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;
#define MOD 1000000007
#define fo(i,k,n) for(int i=k;i<=n;++i)
#define endl '\n'
ll etf[1000001];
ll spf[1000001];
void sieve(){
    ll i,j;
    for(i=0;i<=1000000;i++) {etf[i]=i;spf[i]=i;}
    for(i=2;i<=1000000;i++){
        if(etf[i]==i){
            for(j=i;j<=1000000;j+=i){
                etf[j]/=i;
                etf[j]*=(i-1);
                if(spf[j]==j)spf[j]=i;
            }
        }
    }
}
void primefacto(ll n,vector<pair<ll,ll>>& vec){
    ll lastprime = 1,k=0;
    while(n>1){
        if(lastprime!=spf[n])vec.push_back(make_pair(spf[n],0));
        vec[vec.size()-1].second++;
        lastprime=spf[n];
        n/=spf[n];
    }
}
void divisors(vector<pair<ll,ll>>& vec,ll idx,vector<ll>& divs,ll num){
    if(idx==vec.size()){
        divs.push_back(num);
        return;
    }
    for(ll i=0;i<=vec[idx].second;i++){
        divisors(vec,idx+1,divs,num*pow(vec[idx].first,i));
    }
}
void solve(){
    ll n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<pair<ll,ll>> vec;
    primefacto(n,vec);
    vector<ll> divs;
    divisors(vec,0,divs,1);
    for(auto it=divs.begin();it!=divs.end();it++){
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
    sieve();
    ll t;cin>>t;
    while(t--) solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. While your answer may help to achieve what the original poster wants, your post offers no guidance or explanation that may help others understand/learn what exactly you are doing and why. Please include more context in your reply, see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

java 8 recursive (works on HackerRank).  This method includes option to sum and return the factors as an integer.

```
    static class Calculator implements AdvancedArithmetic {
        public int divisorSum(int n) {
            if (n == 1)
                return 1;

            Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
            return divisorSum( n, set, 1);
        }

        private int divisorSum(int n, Set<Integer> sum, int start){

            if ( start > n/2 )
                return 0;

            if (n%start == 0)
                sum.add(start);

            start++;

            divisorSum(n, sum, start);

            int total = 0;
            for(int number: sum)
                total+=number;
            return total +n;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work on large numbers.  I will look to adjust algorithm to incorporate square root.

Answer (score 0):

If the prime factors are known those 3 functions can be used to get the divisors:

```
    public static <T> Set<List<T>> generatePowerSet(List<T> list) {
        Set<List<T>> powerSet = new HashSet<>();
        generatePowerSet(list, 0, new ArrayList<>(), powerSet);
        return powerSet;
    }

    private static <T> void generatePowerSet(List<T> list, int index, List<T> current, Set<List<T>> powerSet) {
        if (index == list.size()) {
            powerSet.add(new ArrayList<>(current));
            return;
        }
        // Exclude the current element
        generatePowerSet(list, index + 1, current, powerSet);
        // Include the current element
        current.add(list.get(index));
        generatePowerSet(list, index + 1, current, powerSet);
        current.remove(current.size() - 1);
        // Skip duplicate elements
        while (index + 1 < list.size() && list.get(index) == list.get(index + 1)) {
            index++;
        }
        generatePowerSet(list, index + 1, current, powerSet);
    }
    public SortedListSet<Long> getDivisors(ArrayList<Long> primeFactors){
        SortedListSet<Long> divisors = new SortedListSet<>();
        Set<List<Long>> powerSet = generatePowerSet(primeFactors);
        for (List<Long> innerList:powerSet){
            long divisor = 1;
            for (long innerListEntry:innerList){
                divisor *= innerListEntry;
            }
            divisors.add(divisor);
        }
        return divisors;
    }
```