# method of factorization- logic

Tags: algorithm, math, logic, prime-factoring

I have seen many writing factorization logic like this
1. starting from **i = 2**
2. using **i*i <= number** condition  for loop

```
for(int i = 2; i*i <= number; i++){
 if(number % i == 0)
   // some code
}
```

My doubt is:
   what is the need of using i*i<=number. What is he optimizing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factors of a number are paired. For example, the number `30` has factors `1`, `2`, `3`, `5`, `6`, `10`, `15`, and `30`:

```
1  2  3  5
|  |  |  |
30 15 10 6
```

So you don't need to calculate all factors, just the first half of them, and get the other half by a simple operation of division.

Related question： [Efficiently getting all divisors of a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753839/efficiently-getting-all-divisors-of-a-given-number).

Comment: +1 SO, we can eliminate all other divisors (factor pairs) by only using upto sqrt(number). In some cases the n remains as a prime number. Ex 58. We iterate only upto 7, by now number is 29, loop exits. If number remains still greater than 1 (as 29>1 here) after loop exits. We should take care of that number, that MUST BE A PRIME.