# How to use a range given by the user in the for loop in c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Write a program to display all the proper divisors of each one of the numbers in a range of integers given by the first and last values of the range.

The proper divisors of a number n are the positive integers divisors smaller than n.

Input
Two integers a, b which represent the range of the values.

Where 2 <= a < b <= 100

Output
For each value in the range, the program must display the word VALUE and then the number, then in the next line the word DIVISORS followed by a blank space and then each one of the proper divisors of the number separated by a blank space, at the end there must be an end of line character.

This is what I have until now and I'm looking for a simple answer because I am a beginner [image]

Comment: Post code as text not as image. See also [Efficiently getting all divisors of a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753839/efficiently-getting-all-divisors-of-a-given-number)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I strongly recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask] and at least the [Asking Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) portion of the Help Center so you have a better idea of how to use Stack Overflow. For example, never post images of text. They exclude too many people who, for one reason or another, cannot see the image.

Comment: To input multiple numbers you would need a loop and an array or better a [`std::vector<int>`](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/) to store the inputs in. Side note, give your variables readable names it makes it easier for everybody (including your future you) to understand the code.  eg. `a` would becomd `divisor` and `i` would become `value`. Also stop using `using namespace std`.

Comment: Your code is poorly formatted - indenting it sensibly makes it easier to read. It shouldn't even be compiling - line 8 is in the wrong place for a start.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem, by first reading the requriements and then come up with a design. After the design you can start to write the code.

So, what needs to be done?

- Read 2 values, the begin of a range and the end of a range
- Check, if reading of this 2 values was successful and nobody enetered for example "ABC"
- Check, if the given values are valid and form a range
- After having a valid range, we will iterate over all values in the range using a for loop
- As required, we will show the current value in a separate line
- Then, we try to find all divisors for this value. For this, we use a second loop and try, if a division of the value by a potential divisor can be done without any rest
- In that case, we found a proper divisor and output it.
- After having shown all proper divisors on one line, we will start a new line
- (If no valid range was given, we issue an error message)

This can be then implemented for example like the below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    // Inform user that he has to input 2 values
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter a range, so 2 values betwenn 2 and 100 (inclusive): ";
    
    // Read 2 values and check, if thery are valid
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    if ((std::cin >> a >> b) and (a >= 2) and (a < 100) and (b > 2) and (b <= 100) and (a < b)) {

        // Now we have read a valid range
        // Iterate over this range
        for (int value = a; value <= b; ++value) {

            // Show the value to the user
            std::cout << "VALUE " << value << '\n';

            // Now find all the divisors for this value
            for (int potentialDivisor = 1; potentialDivisor < value; ++potentialDivisor) {

                // Check, if it is a proper Divisor
                if (value % potentialDivisor == 0) {

                    // We found a divisor
                    const int properDivisor = potentialDivisor;

                    // Show the resulting divisor
                    std::cout << properDivisor << ' ';
                }
            }
            // Begin a new line for the new value
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "\n*** Error: Invalid input values for range given\n\n";
}
```